# Paginação JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-datatables

Tenho uma `tr` dinâmica que recebe dados de um banco, insiro ele em uma `table` normalmente o problema e que não fica paginado, estou utilizando uma tabela que já vem com paginação e busca pronta ela funciona com `tr` não dinâmicas, mas quando passo para o `tbody` uma `TR` dinâmica ela não faz a paginação.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'Get',
  url: '/mural',
  success: function(data){ 
    var convert = data.lista;
    for(cont = 0;cont < convert.length; cont++)
    { 
      var _dt = new Date(convert[cont].data)
      var parametro =  tableRecados (
          convert[cont].assunto,
          _dt.toLocaleDateString(),
          convert[cont].de,
          convert[cont].id,
          convert[cont].mensagem,
          convert[cont].para
        );
      tableRecados(parametro);
        $("#tbodytable").append(parametro); 
    } 
  },error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
     var msg = '';
     if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Não é possível processar sua solicitação, por favor verifique sua conexão.\n\n[500]';
     } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Não é possível processar sua solicitação, por favor tente novamente.\n\n[404]';
     } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Não é possível processar sua solicitação, por favor verifique sua conexão.\n\n[504]';
     } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Não é possível processar sua solicitação, por favor tente novamente.\n\n[406]';
     } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Não é possível processar sua solicitação, por favor verifique sua conexão.\n\n[508]';
     } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Não é possível processar sua solicitação, por favor tente novamente.\n\n[408]';
     } else {
        msg = 'Não é possível processar sua solicitação, por favor tente novamente.\n\n[410]';
     }             
     alert(msg);
   }
   })
}




  function tableRecados(assunto,data,de,id,msg,para)
     {



         var mensagem = "<tr id='id"+id+"'>";
             mensagem +="<td>"+assunto+"</td>";
             mensagem +="<td>"+data+"</td>";
             mensagem +="<td>"+de+"</td>";
             mensagem +="<td>"+msg+"</td>";
             mensagem +="<td>"+para+"</td>";
             mensagem +="<td class='text-center'>"+'<button type="button"   onclick="deletar(this.id)" class="btn btn-success btn-outline btn-outline-colorless active" style="background-color:#6770b2" class="pull-right">Excluir</button>'+"</td>"
             mensagem +="</tr>";

        return(mensagem);

    }
```

```html
<div class="panel">
     <div class="table-primary">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="datatables">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Assunto</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>De</th>
            <th>Mensagem</th>
            <th>Para</th>
            <th>Gerenciar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbodytable">
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Inclua o código à sua pergunta

Comment: acho que vc precisa reiniciar o plugin que constroi a tabela após fazer o append